# Drawing hour marks of a clock using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-1.x

here is my code:

```
void drawClock(void) 
{ 

glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);


for(int i=0; i<12; i++){

    glRotatef(30,0,0,1);
    glTranslatef(5.2,0.0,0.0);
    glutWireCube(2.0);

}

glFlush(); 
}
```

Here is my reshape function (without it I don't see anything, although I'm not sure how it really works)

```
void changeSize(int w, int h) {
// Prevent a divide by zero, when window is too short
// (you cant make a window of zero width).
if(h == 0) h = 1;
float ratio = 1.0* w / h;
// Reset the coordinate system before modifying
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
// Set the viewport to be the entire window
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
// Set the correct perspective.
gluPerspective(45,ratio,1,1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,70.0, 
0.0,0.0,-1.0,
0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
}
```

So I am trying to draw the hour marks of a clock using wire cubes of size 2.0, and each of these cubes must be 5.2 units away from the center. This is for an assignment, I know it is probably very simple but I just can't manage to make it work properly. My problem is that the cubes appear in 3D, but I want them to appear in 2D, as in I would only see one face. Also, the circle is not centered, I do not understand why. I know I am supposed to use pushMatrix and popMatrix but no matter how I use it it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems you're using a Perspective projection matrix, instead of an orthogonal projection matrix. This would be why it looks '3D'. Perhaps someone can explain it for you further.

Comment: You'll also get a number of people telling you that this is the old way to do things (it is), but if it's what you're learning in class, then it's what your professor will be expecting from you.

Answer (score 3):

**3d Problem**

`gluPerspective` makes a [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection). To accomplish what you need you should apply an [orthographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_%28geometry%29) instead.

The best way to do this with your current code is to us [`glOrtho`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) to provide a left, right, bottom, top, far,near box within which everything will 'appear' 2D. Try the code below in place of `gluPerspective`.

```
glOrtho(10.0f,-10.0f,10.0f,-10.0f,10.0f,-10.0f,10.0f);
```

**Position problem**

I'm not so sure about the transformation as I've not used immediate mode for a while. Note the order of operations makes a difference.

As for the push/pop of matrices, it is basically a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) of 4x4 matrices detailing the transformations. I'm sure it works along the lines of

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslate(x,y,z);// Where x,y,z is the starting point of your clock
for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(i * 30,0,0,1);
    glTranslatef(5.2,0.0,0.0);
    glutWireCube(2.0);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, everything works fine now, I've reviewed some OpenGL and coupled with your answer it's good :) Btw I used glOrtho(-w/40,w/40,-h/40,h/40,1.0f,1000.0f) to have a good view, 40 just so happens to be close enough for me to see well, anyway now it's good thanks